# Php - Enviar Login e Senha para Usuário

Tags: php

Agradeceria ajuda. O sistema que estou criando cadastra aleatoriamente uma senha utilizando Hash e utilizo o email como login. Estes dados estão no BD.
Agora preciso enviar um email ao usuario informando estes dados para que ele possa entrar no sistema.

Estou tentando fazer isso utilizando o arquivo que recebe os dados da tela de cadastro mas não estou tendo sucesso como eu poderia fazer para conseguir resolver isso?

Segue o arquivo adiciona-casal

```
<?php require_once ("conecta.php");?>
<?php require_once ("noivosDAO.php");?>
<?php require_once ("noivos.php");?>

<?php
$noivo = new Noivo();
$noivo->setNome1($_POST["nome1"]) ;
$noivo->setSobrenome1($_POST["sobrenome1"]);
$noivo->setEmail($_POST["email"]);
$noivo->setNome2($_POST["nome2"]);
$noivo->setSobrenome2($_POST["sobrenome2"]);
$noivo->setTelefone($_POST["telefone"]);
$noivo->setRua($_POST["rua"]);
$noivo->setNumero($_POST["numero"]);
$noivo->setCep($_POST["cep"]);
$noivo->setCidade($_POST["cidade"]);
$noivo->setSenha();
$nome_imagem = $noivo->setFoto( $_FILES["foto"]);

$dao = new noivosDAO($conexao);
if ($dao->insereNoivos($noivo, $nome_imagem, $email, $senha)) {
 // Mail it
$email = $_POST["email"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
require_once("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com.br";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$mail->setFrom("xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com.br", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = "Contato site xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$body = "<html>
 <head>
  <title>Registro xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Obrigado por se registrar em nosso site, segue abaixo seu login e senha 
 para acesso:</p>
 <table>
<tr>
 <p> Login: {$email}</p>
</tr>
<tr>
  <p> Senha: {$senha}</p>
</tr>
<tr>
  <p>Link para acesso: <a href 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/login.php'</a></p>
</tr>
  </table>
 </body>
 </html>"
 ;
if($mail->Send())
    $msg = "<center><h1>Dados enviados com sucesso.</h1>
            Você receberá um e-mail para confirmar seu cadastro.<br/>
            Confirme seu cadastro para receber nossas mensagens.<br/><br/>
            Obrigado.</center>";
else
    $msg = "<center><h1>Dados não enviados</h1>
            Por favor, tente novamente.</center>";
?>
<div>
<?php
    if(isset($msg))
    echo "$msg";
?>
</div>
<?php
var_dump($mail); exit;
 ?>
```

Comment: Qual erro esta retornando ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O PHPMailer lança excepções. Assim podes obter um erro mais especifico com o erro que está a acontecer.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
try {
  // ...
  $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); // Mensagens de erro lançadas pelo PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); // Outros erros que possam ter acontecido
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Foxtrot seguem exceções: Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\adiciona-casal.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: senha in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\adiciona-casal.php on line 21Notice: Undefined index: urlSite in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\adiciona-casal.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined variable: body in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\adiciona-casal.php on line 48Dados não enviados

Por favor, tente novamente.

Comment: Foxtrot, alterei alguns campos e as excessões ficaram assim:Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\adiciona-casal.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: senha in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\adiciona-casal.php on line 21       Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.uni5.net' did not match expected CN=`smtp.xxxxxxxxxxx' in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\class.smtp.php on line 344

Comment: Acredito que não estou conseguindo trazer os dados do email e senha do banco de dados.

Comment: Sim, e tens o set do body `$mail->MsgHTML($body);` antes da sua definição.